# Generate unique ID with React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form in React and I need to generate a unique ID for each item I add. The issue is all the items have the same exact ID even though I've tried these:

- Use `uuid` to generate a new ID each time.
- Save the newly generated ID in a global variable.
- Use `new Date()`.
- Use inputs' attributes to generate a string like: inputs.name + inputs.quantity, etc. but I got an error:
- > 'inputs' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

I need a unique id for each item because items can have the same name and other attributes.

[Here's my code](https://gist.github.com/nguyendviet/c4f80f6d270bfc482755de26f92b9cd0). In my code, I've included comments for what I've tried to solve it.

I've also tried the suggestions below but it still doesn't work. The only way I can think of is to manage each input in a separate state and combine them on form submit but that doesn't seem like the right way to do.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and describe the exact problem you're facing. What makes you say that you need unique id? How exactly have you tried the solutions listed above?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thank for the suggestion. I'm going to include the code. I just thought it'd be too long to post. I need unique id so I can delete item based on id, not by order or name because like I mentioned above, items can have the same attributes. I've also mentioned what I've tried above.

Comment: I meant for you to add a [mcve] inside the question description. Not only the whole code on some off-site service. It doesn't mean to dump your whole codebase into the question, minimal means that you should create a snippet that demonstrate the problem with the minimal code possible. So remove any unused code, duplicate logic (like list of data should only include one or two items, not the whole dataset, etc), any irrelevant styling or HTML structure, etc.

Comment: Right. Let me remove the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I paste it here just in case someone else has the same problem:

- I need to trigger a new ID in the handleSubmitItem
- AND: clear out the input to prevent the user hits enter for the same input continuously => React will record it as the same input with the same id.

```js
function handleSubmitItem(event: React.FormEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (newItem.name !== '') {
        // Generate a unique id
        newItem.id = uuidv4(); 
        setGroceries([...groceries, newItem]);
        // Clear input:
        setNewItem(defaultNewItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding id to setValues for item creation?

```
setValues({
    ...inputs,
    id: uuid()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Doing that won't work because the new item needs an id. Adding uuid() there won't add the unique id to the object which is added to the list.

Comment: @Viet maybe you could manage the item creation inside some kind of function where an id is added, then use that function both with `setValues` like above, and when adding new items.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try that to see if it works for me.

Comment: I've tried that. It still doesn't work. I've updated my gist above.